# How to protect Google In-App Billing v3 from code hacking?

Tags: android, security, in-app-billing

Google provides a [convenient API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) to implement "in-app purchase" features on an Android app.

Along with these docs, there is also a [dedicated chapter](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) regarding the security level of this system and the good ways to design it.
The web is full of articles about this step, from [public key protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085279/in-app-billing-security) to [remote server validation](http://evendanan.net/2012/03/In-App-Purchase-Verification-using-PHP-OR-Making-sure-you-ain-t-getting-ripped-off-PHP-style/), but I really can't understand why all of these techniques should work when the main problem is, simply, **code hacking**.

Maybe there is a better term to explain it, but let me do a quick example. The basic idea of my application is that, at certain points, the user can't proceed unless he has purchased an item.

Something like:

```
public void accessTheVeryCoolFeature() {

    boolean haveIt = checkIfPurchased("verycoolfeature");
    if (haveIt) {
        // YEAH! let's open this very cool feature I paid 200 bucks for
    }
    else {
        // ok... where is my wallet?
        boolean purchased = startPurchaseFlow("verycoolfeature");
        if (purchased) {
            // my wallet is now empty but happy
        }
    }
}
```

Following the previous guidelines, the developer can protect his app during the purchase process, letting the `startPurchaseFlow` method to query a remote, trusted, server that validates the receipt.
Purchases done using a "fake marketplace" should be avoided by this.

Another method is to protect the unlocked content by obfuscating the code. This is really simple with tools like ProGuard and should make the life of an "hacker" a bit harder.

Now, I tried to act the part of an hacker that want to read my code, especially the billing phase.
It took me like 1 minute to spot the code I wrote in the previous example. Now the best part: what if I edit the (obfuscated) source code to do this?

```
public void atvf() {

    boolean hi = cip("verycoolfeature");
    hi = true; // <------------------------ AHAH!
    if (hi) {
        // YEAH! let's open this very cool feature for free
    }
    // ...
}
```

All the good words about remote verification and code obfuscation are totally gone. So why spend hours on trying to implement them when the very first problem is in a **boolean value**?

Am I missing something?

Comment: In general, the problem you're describing exists for any app that has runtime licensing independent of the platform. While the use of Java makes it a bit easier to hack Android apps than using C++ for a native Windows app, they're both hackable. At least in the US, such modification is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your app is heavily dependent on its functionality being in a server - as in each functionality stays on the server and the app is just a client tool to call those server APIs, there is nothing you can do. If indeed it's a server-based app - you can check each incoming request (e.g. the app can send a one time session hash) if a valid transaction exists for it and is paid. If not, deny the request.

The app's code is running on the client's phone. If the hacker gains access to that code and is free to modify it to override any billing validations - there is nothing you can do. You should make sure he doesn't gain access to that source code in the first place.